# How can i combine years and month variables on pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 integer variables in pandas dataframe. These are months and years. I want to combine them into one variable like 2021-1. Each index is matching one-to-one (No problem).New variable must be the time series. How can I do that.

For example my dataframe seems like this:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4]
c = pd.DataFrame(a , columns=["Year"])
d = pd.DataFrame(b , columns = ["Month"])
e = pd.concat([c,d] , axis = 1)
e.head()
```

Comment: Please share the data as example, it will be easier if you're talink about different columns, dataframe, also what are the type, str or int ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this,  two examples:

```
import datetime as dt

r = pd.date_range("1-jan-2018", freq="M", periods=24)
df = pd.DataFrame({"year":r.year, "month":r.month})

df.assign(ymstr=df.astype({"year":"string","month":"string"}).apply("-".join, axis=1),
         ymdt=df.apply(lambda r: dt.datetime(r[0],r[1], 1).strftime("%Y-%-m"), axis=1))
```

|  | year | month | ymstr | ymdt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018 | 1 | 2018-1 | 2018-1 |
| 1 | 2018 | 2 | 2018-2 | 2018-2 |
| 2 | 2018 | 3 | 2018-3 | 2018-3 |
| 3 | 2018 | 4 | 2018-4 | 2018-4 |
| 4 | 2018 | 5 | 2018-5 | 2018-5 |
| 5 | 2018 | 6 | 2018-6 | 2018-6 |
| 6 | 2018 | 7 | 2018-7 | 2018-7 |
| 7 | 2018 | 8 | 2018-8 | 2018-8 |
| 8 | 2018 | 9 | 2018-9 | 2018-9 |
| 9 | 2018 | 10 | 2018-10 | 2018-10 |
| 10 | 2018 | 11 | 2018-11 | 2018-11 |
| 11 | 2018 | 12 | 2018-12 | 2018-12 |
| 12 | 2019 | 1 | 2019-1 | 2019-1 |
| 13 | 2019 | 2 | 2019-2 | 2019-2 |
| 14 | 2019 | 3 | 2019-3 | 2019-3 |
| 15 | 2019 | 4 | 2019-4 | 2019-4 |
| 16 | 2019 | 5 | 2019-5 | 2019-5 |
| 17 | 2019 | 6 | 2019-6 | 2019-6 |
| 18 | 2019 | 7 | 2019-7 | 2019-7 |
| 19 | 2019 | 8 | 2019-8 | 2019-8 |
| 20 | 2019 | 9 | 2019-9 | 2019-9 |
| 21 | 2019 | 10 | 2019-10 | 2019-10 |
| 22 | 2019 | 11 | 2019-11 | 2019-11 |
| 23 | 2019 | 12 | 2019-12 | 2019-12 |

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```
from datetime import

e['NewTime'] = e.apply(lambda row: datetime.strptime(f"{int(row.Year)}- 
{int(row.Month)}", '%Y-%m'), axis=1)
```